# Detect if quarter/half year is determined by month end or month start

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For this particular problem, I am unable to come up with the logic or process for how to handle this, and will like some help.

Given two dataframes, represented by quarters and half year

df1: Quarters (represented by month start)

```
 ID    Date     Volume
 1   2020-04      2
 1   2020-07      5
 1   2020-10      1
 1   2021-01      8
```

df2:  Half Year (represented by month start)

```
 ID    Date     Volume
 1   2020-07      7
 1   2021-01      9
 2   2019-07      11
 2   2020-01      14
```

Is there a way python(pandas) can detect IF these are represented by month end or month start.

IF represented by month start, ALWAYS convert to month end. IF represented by month end, make no changes.

In this instance, both would by converted to month start so that dataframe looks like:

Expected output:

df1: Quarters

```
 ID    Date     Volume
 1   2020-03      2
 1   2020-06      5
 1   2020-9      1
 1   2020-12      8
```

df2:  Half Year

```
 ID    Date     Volume
 1   2020-06      7
 1   2020-12      9
 2   2019-06      11
 2   2019-12      14
```

This can easily be done using pd.OffSets(months=x) .. the main challenge here is python being able to detect month end vs month start.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2},
 'Date': {0: '2020-07', 1: '2021-01', 2: '2019-07', 3: '2020-01'},
 'Volume': {0: 7, 1: 9, 2: 11, 3: 14},
 'source': {0: 'half_y', 1: 'half_y', 2: 'half_y', 3: 'half_y'}})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')
df['Quarter'] = df['Date'].dt.quarter
df['Half_year'] = (df['Quarter'] > 1)*1
```

Pandas is even more powerfull than that:

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html#https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html#) on the left side, all entries staring with: pandas.Series.dt.

So it is even possible to get this:

```
df['Date'].dt.is_month_start
df['Date'].dt.is_month_end
```

or

```
df['Date'].is_quarter_start
df['Date'].is_quarter_end
```

You can also use a simple mapping:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'Date': ['2020-04',
  '2020-07',
  '2020-10',
  '2021-01',
  '2020-04',
  '2020-07',
  '2020-10',
  '2021-01'],
 'Volume': [2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 5, 1, 8],
 'source': ['quarter',
  'quarter',
  'quarter',
  'quarter',
  'half_y',
  'half_y',
  'half_y',
  'half_y']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df_map = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 'Quarter': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
 'Trimester': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]})
df.merge(df_map, on=['Month'])
```

Comment: This looks effective for quarters. But gets messy when dealing when half years, and trimesters.

Comment: My initial thought process was checking if the month is a multiple of 3 (for quarters and half year) or multiple of 4 (for trimester). IF not, then map it to the correct month using a python dictiontary

Comment: @tjjudge why does it gets messy with half years? A dictionary is a good solution. You can get even better performance if you convert it to a dataframe and do a merge. You can simply use: 'df['Date'].month` and merge half year, trisemester on that.

Comment: messy because there is no 'dt.halfyear' or 'dt.trimester' on pandas. Because I have a big dataset (over 50,000 rows). Using a dictionary might be the best option here.

Comment: a merge might not work here because we need a generalized script. that can work on multiple dataframes

Comment: @tjjudge why would a merge not work? I updated the example to show how it would work.

Comment: This doesn't work, because in trimester for example, 2021-01 is trimester 3 - when represented by month start. Your merge solution places it at trimester 1

Comment: Seems I do not exectly understand what you want. Could you explain what 2021-01 would be Trimster 3? For me it is clearly the start of Trimester 1 in 2021

Comment: Ok, so using trimester as an example. It can be represent in two ways, month end (2020-31-01) which signifies trimester 3. OR it can also be represented as month start(2021-01-01). Same with half year, first half of the year can either be 2020-06-30 (month end) or 2020-07-01 (month start)

Comment: Does this make sense?